# How to make splitChunks generate commonjs requires() statements?

Tags: typescript, webpack, webpack-4, commonjs

I have the following Webpack configuration. My application consists of a bunch of scripts deployed to AWS Lambdas, so the target is Node and CommonJS. Each script is entry point, though I've limited it just to two for the sake of the example.

The entry points often use the same libraries/dependencies as one another so the resulting files contain a lot of duplication which I'm trying to reduce.

I added the `optimization` section containing `splitChunks` and the output files in `/dist` look a lot better. Each entry point file has been reduced a lot, and the new `vendor.js` is a lot bigger. The total filesize was reduced by more than 5x.

The problem is that doing so has broken my application. It can no longer resolve the dependencies properly. I put Webpack into development mode so that I could skim the output. I checked inside the generated `add-comment.js` and there is no reference to anything like `require('./vendor.js')`, and in fact no uses of the word 'vendor' at all.

Is there some configuration I can change so that each entry point gets a reference to `vendor.js`? Or maybe I'm misunderstanding how this is supposed to work?

```
module.exports = [
    {
        name: 'Server',
        mode: 'development',
        entry: {
            'add-comment': './server/add-comment.ts',
            'delete-comment': './server/delete-comment.ts'
        },
        output: {
            filename: 'server/[name].js',
            libraryTarget: 'commonjs'
        },
        target: 'node',
        resolve: {
            extensions: ['.ts', '.js']
        },
        module: {
            rules: [
                {
                    test: /\.ts$/,
                    exclude: /node_modules/,
                    use: [{
                        loader: 'ts-loader',
                        options: {
                            configFile: "server/tsconfig.json"
                        }
                    }]
                }
            ]
        },
        externals: ['aws-sdk'],
        optimization: {
            splitChunks: {
                name: 'vendor',
                chunks: 'all'
            }   
        }
    }
]
```

Not sure if it's relevant, but this my tsconfig. `"module": "commonjs"` and a few other thing are brought in by the `extends` directive. [Here's the rest](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@tsconfig/node14)

```
{
    "$schema": "https://json.schemastore.org/tsconfig",
    "extends": "@tsconfig/node14/tsconfig.json",
    "compilerOptions":
    {
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "target": "ES2019",
        "strict": false,
        "types": ["jest", "webpack-env"]
    }
}
```

If I use the [HtmlWebpackPlugin](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin) (which is not applicable to my situation since I'm targeting Node, not a browser) then it will generate the scripts in the following order.

```html
<script src="server/vendor.js"></script>
<script src="server/add-comment.js"></script>
<script src="server/delete-comment.js"></script>
```

So Webpack clearly knows that that vendor needs to be loaded first, but something about my configuration means that it doesn't understand how my code is being invoked. I have `target: 'node'` already, maybe I need something else.

Comment: Do you need webpack for what you are trying to do? If your app is 100% ts/js and on the server, you should be able to do what you are asking with `tsc`, no bundler needed.

Comment: @ConnorLow Possibly not. There's a client as well as a server, and since the client uses webpack to bundle things (React, etc.) it's reasonably convenient to have both modules follow a similar build workflow. But I'd be open to changing it. My question about moving to tsc would be how the 3rd party stuff makes it into the final artifact. Right now, I just zip the contents of `dist/server`. I thought the bundler was necessary for tree shaking and determining which dependencies are actually used

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been [implemented in Webpack 5](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/pull/8575). As far as I know there is no plan to backport it.

There's an incompatibility between Webpack 4 and Webpack 5. The `output` section needs to change to this:

```
output: {
    filename: 'server/[name].js',
    library {
        type: 'commonjs'
    }
},
```